# Need help converting LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 to openGl libgdx Pixmap

Tags: libgdx, directx9

What i'm trying to achieve. I need to know the equivalent of `LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9` to openGL, the problem is I only know `Pixmap` class of libgdx which `pixmap.drawPixel(x, y, color)` is only available, I cannot find how to convert `layer->lightMap->LockRect(0, &rectLock, 0, 0)`

Below is example code of c, `LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9` lightMap is used which unknown in openGL to me.

```
D3DLOCKED_RECT rectLock;
D3DCOLOR* pixels;
LandLayer* layer;
int j;

for (int i = 0; i < m_layers.GetSize(); i++)
{
    layer = m_layers[i];
    layer->lightMap->LockRect(0, &rectLock, 0, 0);
    pixels = (D3DCOLOR*)rectLock.pBits;
    for (j = 0; j < MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE; j++)
        pixels[j] = D3DCOLOR_ARGB(layer->alphaMap[j], m_colorMap[j * 3], m_colorMap[j * 3 + 1], m_colorMap[j * 3 + 2]);
    layer->lightMap->UnlockRect(0);
}
```

What I have done in kotlin, using `Pixmap` from libgx https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.java

```
tmpColor.set( Color.toIntBits( r.toInt(),g.toInt(),b.toInt(),a.toInt()))
pixmap.drawPixel(x, y, tmpColor.toIntBits())
```

Answer (score 2):

LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 is a texture object. OpenGL, by comparison to Direct3D, is weakly-typed, so there is no class or struct that is equivalent; instead texture objects are represented by unsigned integer "names" - the same GLuint data type that is used for other object types.

From the code you posted it looks as though you're trying to set texture data from a system memory array. The OpenGL calls to do this are glTexImage2D (for creating a new texture) or glTexSubImage2D (for updating an existing texture) - assuming a 2D texture, of course. There is no direct OpenGL equivalent to LockRect.